# how to declare multiple variable names with loop in c#

Tags: c#, string

How can I declare multiple variable names within a loop in c#

Is there any way to do declare the n strings by loop

i don't have to use array..please if this can be done without array then please tell it will be very helpful to me

For example:-

```
String st1 = "";
String st2 = "";
String st3 = "";
String st4 = "";
String st5 = "";
```

If there is any way to do this then please help

Comment: You could declare an array and then loop through it to initialize the elements.

Comment: You can use a List<string> or an Array (string[]) instead. We need more info.

Comment: Are you attempting to create an undefined number of variables? Do you need new, *individual* variables?

Comment: i don't have to use array..please if i can to this without array then it will be very helpful to me

Comment: You have to use a collection/array of some form to do what you want.

Comment: i want to use this collections not array..so how can i assign it??

Comment: hey i got the answer from Hayden..then why people are doing down vote to this question??thins is not fare

Comment: Could you please clarify your question since you know the answer? Also please remove all "thank you" text as not directly related to a problem while clarifying the question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i found the answer and i applied to my program like this to declare i did `List<string> strList = new List<string>();

                for (int q = 0; q < n; q++)
                {
                    string st = "";
                    strList.Add(st);
                }` and then to print i did this `foreach (string str in strList) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(str);
                    }` and also i just removed all the thanks from the post..now please don't downvote the question unnecessary

Comment: Downvote seem to be quite necessary - question still does not relates much to accepted answer and half of the post is taken by "please help" text. The fact that you found answer that you are interested in does not make question to be better quality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if I am interpreting your question right, you can declare an `array` or `list`, then initialize these `elements` in a loop

For example (array) (if you want a fix number of elements):

```
int n = 10; // number of strings

string[] str = new string[n]; // creates a string array of n elements

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    str[i] = ""; // set the value "" at position i in the array
}
```

(list) (if you don't want a fix number of elements)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

...
int n = 10;
List<string> str = new List<string>(); // creates a list of strings
// List<string> str = new List<string>(n) to set the number it can hold initially (better performance)

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    list.Add(""); // if you've set an initial capacity to a list, be aware that elements will go after the pre allocated elements
}

list[0] = "hello world"; // how to use a List
list[list.Count - 1] = "i am the last element"; // list.Count will get the total amount of elements in this list, and we minus 1 to fix indexing
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without array then please tell me it will be very helpful

Comment: @PalashSachan This method actually creates a variable length array, depending on how many you want to create (`n`). So this could work for you if you don't know the value of `n`.

Comment: @PalashSachan updated my answer to include a list example and how to use it (usage is very similar to an array, but it is not a fixed size)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know how many strings you need, use a `List<string>`

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < loopTotal; i++)
{
    string s = "foo";
    strList.Add(s);
}
```

When you use a `List`, you can have a collection of variables, without a defined count. You can have anywhere between 0 and (insert max number here).

---

If you *do* know how many strings you need, you can use an asray of `string[]`:

```
string[] Array = new string { "", "", "", "", "" };

foreach (int i = 0; i < Array.Count(); i++)
{
    Array[i] = "foo";
}
```

This makes sure that each item in the array has a value. However, being a defined list, you might want to instead use a `foreach`, which will use the Array count as a loop counter:

```
foreach (string s in Array)
{
    Array[s] = "foo";
}
```

Comment: will this "List<string>" and with "str.List.Add(s)" will create the n string ??

Comment: What this does is create a new string, set the variable to whatever you want, then add that to a list. So if you loop this 5 times, you will have a List with 5 strings in it. If you loop it 500 times, you will have a list with 500 strings in it.

Comment: You can find out more about [Lists here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Either add these values to a collection...

```
String s1 = "text";
var c = new List<string>(new [s1]);
```

Then loop. Vars are still explicit but you reference them from collection.

Or, you could look at reflection [msdn example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.localvariableinfo(v=vs.110).aspx). As a rule reflection is not great for performance.

Out of curiosity, it would be good to know why arrays are not permitted.

Edit : this includes an example of a collection initialiser as per comments. Different collection have different constructors, but list allows you to pass an ienumerable to get it started. This example creates an inline array to add to the collection.