# Assign random letter to each variable

Tags: c#

How can I cycle through variables and assign a random letter to each?

Without having to do:

```
var1 = RandomLetter();
var2 = RandomLetter();
var3 = RandomLetter();
var4 = RandomLetter();
var5 = RandomLetter();
```

This will produce all having the same letter:

```
var1 = var2 = var3 = RandomLetter();
```

---

I'm looking for a way to shorten the process, I need to do this to 50+ variables.

At first I though a foreach loop, but they are null and don't start out in a collection to loop through.

```
// Variables
public static char var1, var2, var3, var4, var5;


// Generate Random Letter
public static Random random = new Random();
public static char RandomLetter()
{
    const string text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    int index = random.Next(text.Length);
    return text[index];
}
```

Comment: Can't you put them in a collection to loop through?

Comment: Can't you use an array: `var letters = new char[50];` + a loop to fill it ?

Comment: use `char array`

Comment: "they are null and don't start out in a collection to loop through.". Why aren't they in a collection? Is there any reason they can't be declared as one, or at least put into one for processing? This would be the obvious solution, just like any list of things of the same type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to declare multiple variable names with loop in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140196/how-to-declare-multiple-variable-names-with-loop-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of (irrelevant) numbers, and then convert every (irrelevant) number into a random character.

```
var randomLetterList = Enumerable.Range(0, 50)
                            .Select(x => RandomLetter())
                            .ToArray();
```

---

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 50)
```

This returns a list of 50 numbers, starting at 0: `[ 0 , 1 , 2 , ... , 49 ]`

```
.Select(x => RandomLetter())
```

This turns every element of the list into a random letter (notice that the actual **value** of the number is never used): e.g. `[ 'b' , 'h' , 'm' , ... , 'o' ]`.

The important thing to note here is that the resulting list will contain **exactly** as many letters, as the initial list had numbers.

```
.ToArray();
```

This just converts the `IEnumerable<char>` into a `char[]`. This allows you to access the letters by using their index.

Instead of using

- `var1`
- `var2`
- `var3`
- ...
- `var50`

you instead use:

- `randomLetterList[0]`
- `randomLetterList[1]`
- `randomLetterList[2]`
- ...
- `randomLetterList[49]`

Answer (score 5):

Don't use separate variables, use a collection instead:

```
List<char> letters = 
    Enumerable.Range(1,50)
              .Select(i => RandomLetter())
              .ToList();
```

Comment: best and short answer

Comment: @MongZhu: OP shouldn't be using the separate variables in the first place. `myVar1` can just as easily be accessed as `myVarList[1]`, with the added benefit of actually being able to use loops to process the list at some point.

Comment: I get that, and I agree entirely to use a collection here. I thought may be you have some awesome distribution trick up your sleeve;)

Comment: Thanks all, I've given you upvotes. I accepted the other answer because of the detailed description and examples. There is a typo, change -> to =>, it wont let me make an edit.

Comment: @MongZhu No magic to do here - there's not a way to create dynamically named local variables.